# Google Analytics Data Export API V3

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I am trying to get to grips with interacting with the GA API v3 using php. Being quite new to php, I am struggling somewhat. Does anyone here have any experience with using the api with php (v3)?

http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/analytics/docs/index.html

Google does supply a small sample script but it's effectively useless (with my limited skills) as it returns an api key but doesn't tell you where it needs to go or why you need it.

If anyone has any knowledge I would be very grateful if you could show me how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you register you API with Google from their API console. Make sure you turn on Google Analytics, and create a project.

After make sure you download the full api from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list).

You want to go into simple.php located in the Analytics folder (under examples) and uncomment lines 11-14, and replace with information from Google API Console:

```
$client->setClientId('xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://www.xxxx.com/xxx/examples/analytics/simple.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxx');
```

This will let you connect and you will see the basic data. For more details and a great tutorial you can see it [here](http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=198).

Your total page should look like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/apiAnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=analytics to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('addyourshere');
$client->setClientSecret('addyourshere');
$client->setRedirectUri('addyourshere');
$client->setDeveloperKey('addyourshere');
$service = new apiAnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

  $props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
 print "<h1>Web Properties</h1><pre>" . print_r($props, true) . "</pre>";

  $accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
  print "<h1>Accounts</h1><pre>" . print_r($accounts, true) . "</pre>";

  $segments = $service->management_segments->listManagementSegments();
  print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($segments, true) . "</pre>";

  $goals = $service->management_goals->listManagementGoals("~all", "~all", "~all");
 print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($goals, true) . "</pre>";



  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial. I have been trying to find something on it for a while now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: For some reason I just get a message saying "Connect me!" which I click and then it loads a little bit of code saying, "Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:" but doesn't tell me what this is or where to put it! I have got all the above information in the php file?

Comment: "Connect Me" is what you want to see. The PHP example will first let you connect, and then it should print out all your data into a PHP Array. Just fill in your 4 elements outlined in my earlier comment and it should work. I just tried with the latest from the SVN without issue.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't do that for me. It prints a line of saying "Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:" then there is a box with a string of text and numbers but it doesn't tell me where I need to put the this string of text.

Comment: I have added the exact code I have working. Just change your variables and it should work.

Comment: Many thanks for that. Would you be able to tell me where I find my developer key? I cannot see that in the console at all?

Comment: In fact I now have the code running (seems it doesn't like it from localhost under mamp) however WITHOUT a developer key. It loads all the arrays although that's not particularly pretty! Thanks for you help and I hope you can help me locate the developer key.

Comment: the developerkey is in the Google API console, under Simple API Access. The API key is the developer key. Google needs to rename this to make it clearer :)

Comment: Ah Adrian thank you very much! And I second your sentiment on Google making things clearer.